# REST API Query Timeout Expected

Tags: api, rest, timeout

Having recently completed an integration with salesforce using the REST API we've come across an interesting feature.

All the documentation I could find suggests that we should get a QUERY_TIMEOUT error if a query runs longer than 120 seconds.

This has led to some .NET "A Task was canceled" errors when using async Tasks to send the query.

As it turns out we had the HttpClient set to timeout at 140 seconds and the client was timing out before the server. Raising the client timeout to 10 minutes has solved the issue for us.

So, my questions are these:

- Is it possible to have the server query time-out extended?
- If so, how is this achieved through the back end or a support call?
- If not, have we uncovered a bug and has anybody else had similar issues?